# Oracle - Create a function that has the system date as a default parameter that returns all rows meeting a certain condition on the parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In oracle I have a table that has multiple columns, two of which are date columns. I want to create a parameterized function where given an input date I would like to return all the rows where the input date is between the two date columns. In addition, if the user doesn't pass an input - I have to use system date as the default parameter.

I've tried to create a pipelined function to do this, however when I try to use an if condition such as

```
create or replace function abc (v_date in date) return table_type pipelined;
begin 
if v_date is null then
 for row in (select a, b, c from abc where sysdate between abc.date1, abc.date2) LOOP
 pipe row(table_type(a, b, c));
else
 for row in (select a, b, c from abc where v_date between abc.date1, abc.date2) LOOP
 pipe row(table_type(a, b, c));
end if;
end loop;
return;
```

I've tried variations of this but I keep getting errors like - found else, expecting end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `IF` when you have `NVL`... you do however need to fix the `BETWEEN` operator which expects an `AND`, not a comma.

```
create or replace function abc (v_date in date) return table_type pipelined;
begin 
  for row in (select a, b, c from abc where NVL(v_date,sysdate) between abc.date1 AND abc.date2)
  loop
    pipe row(table_type(a, b, c));
  end loop;
  return;
end;
```

Comment: why use nvl when coalesce runs faster

Comment: Is COALESCE really faster?

Comment: Ohh this is neat!

Comment: I just tested NVL vs COALESCE on 1 billion iterations... NVL took  00:00:00.000009000, COALESCE took 00:00:00.000011000. COALESCE was negligibly slower. Even if it was faster, I cannot conceive of a situation in any Oracle app I know of that the difference would be noticeable.

Comment: On an other note - I keep getting db errors when the function uses any parameter. If I don't give it a parameter at all then it works. What do you think causes this?

Comment: @Prateek, you would have to show us exactly what call you are making with what parameter, and how your function looks right now in case you've changed it, and what the Oracle error is.

Comment: I figured it out, I was unable to replace the function. Strange. Thank you

Comment: @PaulW -- That is what I've seen on some website.  Not a great reference I'll admit and I have not tested it myself personally.  Just made note of it because it aligned with the standard

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option.

Setting date format (you don't have to do it):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Sample table:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID DATE_FROM  DATE_TO
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 15.01.2022 18.02.2022
         2 20.01.2022 30.01.2022
         3 15.08.2022 31.08.2022
         4 01.02.2023 28.02.2023
```

Function accepts date parameter which defaults to truncated sysdate. It returns refcursor.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_datum in date default trunc(sysdate))
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select * from test
  7      where par_datum between date_from and date_to;
  8    return rc;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.
```

Testing: with no parameter, sysdate is being used:

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

        ID DATE_FROM  DATE_TO
---------- ---------- ----------
         4 01.02.2023 28.02.2023
```

Passing parameter value:

```
SQL> select f_test(date '2022-01-25') from dual;

F_TEST(DATE'2022-01-
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

        ID DATE_FROM  DATE_TO
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 15.01.2022 18.02.2022
         2 20.01.2022 30.01.2022


SQL>
```

Comment: now its just Flexing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I decided to accept the other answer though because I wanted to go without cursors

Answer (score 1):

Just use coalesce then you don't need the if statement

```
for row in (select a, b, c from abc where coalesce(v_date,sysdate) between abc.date1 and abc.date2) LOOP
pipe row(table_type(a, b, c));
```